# Reading an Environment Variable set at CodePipeline from a CodeBuild buildspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, environment-variables, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I've setup an AWS CodePipeline named **test-pipeline-flow**.

The **Source** step has being set to use an **AWS CodeCommit** named **test-repo**.

The **Build** step has being set to use an **AWS CodeBuild** named **test-build-repo**. This **CodeBuild** has the following **buildspec.yml**:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  build:
    commands:
       - echo $FOO
       - echo $BAR
```

At the **CodeBuild test-build-repo** I've also set the **Environment Variables** through the **Environment > Additional configuration** sub-section:

[image: Additional configuration]

So the issue here is that when I trigger the **AWS CodePipeline test-pipeline-flow**

The **CloudWatch** logs show that **$FOO** holds `whatever` (as expected) and the **$BAR** actually holds `#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}` instead of the actual **Execution ID**

What else am I missing that not allowing **$BAR** to resolve to the correct value provided by **AWS CodePipeline**?

Answer (score 0):

Based off your screen shot, it looks like you're tryings to use the `CodePipeline` variable syntax on the **`CodeBuild`** configuration page. If so, you need to set the environment variables within Code**Pipeline** page/console.

This page has a detailed description of how the variables are scoped within a pipeline and its actions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html

when you run the following command from cloud-shell or from your local machine you should see something like this:

*notice we are looking at the **pipeline**, not the codebuild project*

```bash
# ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-variables.html

aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name <pipeline-name>

{
    "name": "Build",
    "actions": [
        {
            "outputArtifacts": [
                {
                    "name": "BuildArtifact"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Build",
            "configuration": {
                "EnvironmentVariables": "[{\"name\":\"Execution_ID\",\"value\":\"#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\"},{\"name\":\"Commit_ID\",\"value\":\"#{SourceVariables.CommitId}\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\"}]",
                "ProjectName": "env-var-test"
            },
            "inputArtifacts": [
                {
                    "name": "SourceArtifact"
                }
            ],
            "region": "us-west-2",
            "actionTypeId": {
                "provider": "CodeBuild",
                "category": "Build",
                "version": "1",
                "owner": "AWS"
            },
            "runOrder": 1
        }
    ]
},
```